# 分析のためにゲーム木を描写したくなったとき、利用可能なライブラリ・フレームワークは何がありますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

ターン制の対戦ゲームは、基本的にゲーム木を構築できます。たとえば○×ゲーム(tic-tac-toe)のゲーム木はこちらです。

[Game tree for Tic-Tac-Toe game using MiniMax algorithm.](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Game-tree-for-Tic-Tac-Toe-game-using-MiniMax-algorithm_fig1_262672371)

[image]

今、ふとした分析のために、このようにゲーム木を描写したくなりました。

## 質問

- ゲーム木を描写する機能を持った、つまり、ゲーム木の可視化ができる、何某かの分析フレームワーク/ライブラリなどはありますか?
- OSS で完結していて、無料で利用できるようなものの方が、望ましいです。

Comment: ゲーム木はそもそも木なのでグラフを描くソフトウェアであれば描けそうですが、それでは不十分な理由はありますか？

Comment: なんとなくですが、　graphviz を直接ゴリゴリ書くのは、java と　素朴なsqlクライアント使ってゴリゴリsql書いているような気分になります。もうちょっと、構造化されて、任意のゲーム木を描写しやすくなっててもいいんじゃないのかな、と思い質問した次第です

Comment: これあたりは参考になるでしょうか？ [What's the difference between a game tree and a decision tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6890469/9014308), [dtreeviz : Decision Tree Visualization](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz), [How to visualize decision trees](https://explained.ai/decision-tree-viz/), [free visual editor for graph (dot) files \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3433655/9014308), [Display this decision tree with Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42621190/9014308), [Gradient Boosting Decision Treeを用いたモデルトレーニング...](https://qiita.com/tatsunidas/items/a67e910d6365ce4bcdad)